# Is there a official source restricting the original Enlarge power for the duergar monster?

Tags: adnd-2e, caster-level, duergar

The duergar from *Monstrous Manual* uses the Enlarge power with his hit points as caster level as described on page 97.

The *Complete Book of Dwarves* dictates on page 31 that the caster level is twice his level. *Player's Option: Skills & Powers*, page 25 removed this power completely.

Obviously the authors of the two last books wanted to balance power in player's hands, after all, a player with a 9th level warrior duergar could reach 40' high and damage x10 if they had 90hp.

But a later publication, *The Gates of Firestorm Peak*, an adventure specially designed to Player's Option rules, used freely the monsters with the original 'hp as caster level' statement, as can be seen on page 12 description.

So, besides the 'nerfed' version for players, is there some kind of errata or a Sage Advice (Skip William's column in *Dragon Magazine*) answer pointing to do not use hp as caster level in any official 2e material?

Comment: For context, the MM Duergar had a HD of 1+2 (meaning 3-10 HP), so the caster level would be semi-reasonable (strong for such a weak creature, but still within the bounds of sanity). Obviously such rules in the hands of *much* higher HP PCs would be inappropriate. That said, they do have scaling rules for larger encounters that would give the leader up to 4HD+8 (12-40 HP), which gets kind of nuts for caster level.

Comment: Adding to ShadowRanger comment, the MM also shows until 9th level 'monsters': "...
Duergar are armed as follows: 
1st level: pick, hammer, spear, chain mail, and shield; 
2nd level: pick, light crossbow, chain mail, and shield; 
3rd-6th level: hammer, short sword, plate mail, and shield: 
7th-9th level: hammer*, short sword*, plate mail*, and shield*; 
3rd-6th/3rd-6th-level priest/thief: any usable*/any usable*; 
7th-9h/7th-9th-leveI priest/thief: any usable*/any usable*..."